# Homegroups: Shared folder from Win10 don't show up on Win7 PC, but some other shared folders do

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, network-shares, homegroup

I've shared folders via homegroups successfully before, but I had shared them from a Win7 PC and accessed them from a Win10 one. Now I'm trying to do the reverse, and the folder I'm sharing is not showing up on the other PC.

First I tried to share my `Desktop` folder. But the window with the progressbar was taking forever, so I cancelled it. Then I tried to share just `Desktop\someDir`, which seemed to happen instantaneously. But nothing I shared became visible on the other PC.

Answer (score 0):

While I was typing up the question, it fixed itself.

I'm pretty sure I know what the problem was.

Before I cancelled the `Desktop` share-enabling window, it must have already gotten to `someDir` and shared it. Then when I thought I was enabling sharing for `someDir`, I was actually *toggling* sharing, which means I was disabling it (since it was already enabled it). When I checked the other PC, nothing showed up as shared. That's because, despite me cancelling the `Desktop` share-enabling window, Windows has continued to go through my files in the background and enabling sharing for them.

Then some time after it has silently finished, I checked again in the other PC and the entire `Desktop` folder was suddenly visible there, except for the `someDir` folder. Then I enabled sharing specifically for `someDir` and that let me access all of `Desktop` on the other PC.

**So the fix was basically just to wait some time.**